# UDP Socket Server/Client in C? Socket not sending/receiving data

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, datagram

Cannot get my client to send data to the server, or my server to receive from the client. Any I idea why perhaps? Before coming here, I've tried rewriting the code numerous times, without luck. Still new to UDP Sockets, having trouble with them. Did I make the server/client functions right? Or are they messed up and that's why it's not working properly? Thanks in advance for any help in resolving this issue.

```
/********************************************************************
 * svoip.c - Going to be a simple VOIP (Speak Over NET) application *
 ********************************************************************
 * By Philip R. Simonson                                            *
 ********************************************************************
 */

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define ALIAS "random_str"
#define MYPORT "31337"
#define MAXDATA 1024

typedef BOOL bool;

#define false FALSE
#define true TRUE

/* packet structs */
struct PACKET {
    char data[MAXDATA];
};
typedef struct PACKET packet_t;

struct FRAME {
    bool bArrived;
    packet_t packet;
};
typedef struct FRAME frame_t;

/* helper functions */
void clear_frame(frame_t *frame);
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa);

/* setup functions */
int setup_server(void);
int setup_client(const char *hostname);

/* file functions */
int record_file(void);
int send_file(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_storage *client, const char *filename, frame_t *packet);
int recv_file(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_storage *server, const char *filename, frame_t *packet);
int play_file(const char *filename);

/* main() - entry point for application
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_storage client, addr;
    frame_t frame;

    if(argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [address]\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    clear_frame(&frame);

    WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsaData);
    if(argc == 1) {
        sockfd = setup_server();
        if(recv_file(sockfd, &client, "test.wav", &frame))
            goto error;
        printf("IP   : %s\nPORT : %s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&client)->sin_addr), MYPORT);
        if(play_file("tmp.wav"))
            goto error;
        if(remove("tmp.wav"))
            goto error;
    } else {
        sockfd = setup_client(argv[1]);
        puts("Press any key to record message...");
        getch();
        if(record_file() != 0)
            goto error;
        printf("IP   : %s\nPORT : %s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&addr)->sin_addr), MYPORT);
        if(send_file(sockfd, &addr, "tmp.wav", &frame) != 0)
            goto error;
        if(remove("tmp.wav") != 0)
            goto error;
    }
    if(sockfd != 0)
        closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;

error:
    if(sockfd != 0)
        closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

void clear_frame(frame_t *frame)
{
    frame_t ftmp;
    memset(&ftmp, 0, sizeof(ftmp));
/*  memset(&ftmp.packet, 0, sizeof(ftmp.packet)); */
}

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if(sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int setup_server(void)
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int sockfd;
    int rv;

    printf("*****************************\n"
        "* Tiny VOIP Application     *\n"
        "* By 5n4k3                  *\n"
        "*****************************\n\n");

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    /* loop through all the results and bind to the first it can */
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("listener: socket()");
            continue;
        }

        if(bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("listener: bind()");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }
    if(p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listener: failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    printf("listener: waiting to recvfrom...\n");
    return sockfd;
}

int setup_client(const char *hostname)
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int sockfd;
    int rv;

    printf("*****************************\n"
        "* Tiny VOIP Application     *\n"
        "* By 5n4k3                  *\n"
        "*****************************\n\n");

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if((rv = getaddrinfo(hostname, MYPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    /* loop through all the results and make a socket */
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket()");
            continue;
        }
        if(connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect()");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if(p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to create socket.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    puts("client: socket created.");
    return sockfd;
}

int record_file(void)
{
    char mci_command[100];
    char retstr[300];
    int mci_error;

    /* open wav type alias */
    sprintf(mci_command, "open new type waveaudio alias %s", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, retstr, sizeof(retstr), NULL);

    /* set the time format */
    sprintf(mci_command, "set %s time format ms", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, retstr, sizeof(retstr), NULL);

    sprintf(mci_command, "record %s notify", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, retstr, sizeof(retstr), NULL);

    printf("Now on air, press a key to stop.\n");
    getch();

    sprintf(mci_command, "stop %s", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, retstr, sizeof(retstr), NULL);

    sprintf(mci_command, "save %s %s", ALIAS, "tmp.wav");
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, retstr, sizeof(retstr), NULL);

    sprintf(mci_command, "close %s", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, retstr, sizeof(retstr), NULL);
    printf("Recording stopped.\nPress a key to quit.\n");
    getch();
    return mci_error;
}

int send_file(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_storage *client, const char *filename, frame_t *frame)
{
    FILE *file;
    char *buf;
    char cwd[256];
    int client_len;
    int total_bytes;
    int bytes;

    if(getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot get current working directory.\n");
        return -2;
    }
    strncat(cwd, "\\", sizeof(cwd));
    strncat(cwd, filename, sizeof(cwd));
    if((file = fopen(cwd, "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot read input file.\n");
        close(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    bytes = 0;
    total_bytes = 0;
    frame->bArrived = false;
    while(frame->bArrived == 0) {
        bytes = fread(frame->packet.data, 1, MAXDATA, file);
        if(bytes > 0) {
            total_bytes += bytes;
            if(bytes == MAXDATA) {
                frame->bArrived = true;
            }
        }
        if(bytes == 0)
            break;
    }
    buf = malloc(sizeof(frame_t));
    if(!buf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        fclose(file);
        close(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy(buf, frame, sizeof(frame_t));
    client_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
    if(sendto(sockfd, buf, sizeof(frame_t), 0, (struct sockaddr *)client, client_len) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't send all of the data.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sent %d bytes of data.\n", total_bytes);
    }
    free(buf);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

int recv_file(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_storage *server, const char *filename, frame_t *frame)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    FILE *file;
    char cwd[256];
    int addrlen;
    int total_bytes;
    int bytes;

    if(getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot get current working directory.\n");
        return -2;
    }
    strncat(cwd, "\\", sizeof(cwd));
    strncat(cwd, filename, sizeof(cwd));
    if((file = fopen(cwd, "wb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot open file for writing.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    bytes = 0;
    total_bytes = 0;
    addr = *((struct sockaddr_in *)server);
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    while((bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, frame->packet.data, MAXDATA, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr,
        &addrlen)) != 0) {
        if(fwrite(frame->packet.data, 1, bytes, file) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't write all of the data.\n");
            break;
        }
        total_bytes += bytes;
    }
    fclose(file);
    if(bytes == 0) {
        printf("Received %d bytes of data.\n", total_bytes);
        frame->bArrived = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int play_file(const char *filename)
{
    if(PlaySound(filename, NULL, SND_FILENAME))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `clear_frame` function ignores the parameter passed to it. You can only `bind` a socket once, so the loops in `setup_server` and `setup_client` make no sense. Why do you both `connect` the socket and use `sendto`? If it's connected, it only goes to one place. How are you expecting your `recvfrom` loop to know when it has received the whole file, given that UDP is connectionless? Also, where's the transmit pacing, out of order detection, retransmission, and all the other stuff UDP doesn't do for you that your code requires to work sanely?

Comment: So what your are saying is, "Better to rewrite the entire program in TCP?". Or it'll be a mess of code by the time it's done. How would I go about adding stuff, is there a resource on learning UDP socket programming in C. I'm new to UDP, if you couldn't tell.

Comment: UDP is really not for amateurs since you have to do yourself all the things TCP does for you, unless you are sure you don't need them. But if you really want to do it, start by looking closely at existing protocols layered on top of UDP such as TFTP.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'll do research and I will rewrite this in TCP for now. Until I learn more about UDP.